# TCP Socket Server custom class for socket identifier in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I've been looking at many tcp client/server examples and would want to know how one can go about creating a method to identify each client. One way I know is through lets say, a log in authentication. I know how to connect, and query a database, but how would I lets say after successful authentication, take the username and say this username is this socket. A class example or simple method would be appreciated as an example. I want to be able to target all connected clients by their username from a database individually.

Example I'm using for server

```
 using System;

    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Net;

    using System.Net.Sockets;

    using System.Text;



    namespace MultiServer

    {

        class Program

        {

            private static readonly Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            private static readonly List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();

            private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

            private const int PORT = 100;

            private static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];



            static void Main()

            {

                Console.Title = "Server";

                SetupServer();

                Console.ReadLine(); // When we press enter close everything

                CloseAllSockets();

            }



            private static void SetupServer()

            {

                Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");

                serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));

                serverSocket.Listen(0);

                serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);

                Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete");

            }



            /// <summary>

            /// Close all connected client (we do not need to shutdown the server socket as its connections

            /// are already closed with the clients).

            /// </summary>

            private static void CloseAllSockets()

            {

                foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)

                {

                    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

                    socket.Close();

                }



                serverSocket.Close();

            }



            private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)

            {

                Socket socket;



                try

                {

                    socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);

                }

                catch (ObjectDisposedException) // I cannot seem to avoid this (on exit when properly closing sockets)

                {

                    return;

                }



               clientSockets.Add(socket);

               socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);

               Console.WriteLine("Client connected, waiting for request...");

               serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);

            }



            private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)

            {

                Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;

                int received;



                try

                {

                    received = current.EndReceive(AR);

                }

                catch (SocketException)

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");

                    // Don't shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway.

                    current.Close(); 

                    clientSockets.Remove(current);

                    return;

                }



                byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];

                Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);

                string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);

                Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);



                if (text.ToLower() == "get time") // Client requested time

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Text is a get time request");

                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

                    current.Send(data);

                    Console.WriteLine("Time sent to client");

                }

                else if (text.ToLower() == "exit") // Client wants to exit gracefully

                {

                    // Always Shutdown before closing

                    current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

                    current.Close();

                    clientSockets.Remove(current);

                    Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");

                    return;

                }

                else

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Text is an invalid request");

                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Invalid request");

                    current.Send(data);

                    Console.WriteLine("Warning Sent");

                }



                current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't know what examples you've cribbed from but please stop. You have *one* `buffer` variable - and *multiple* client connections. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Not to mention the lack of synchronization around all those global variables. Networking is hard. Multi-threading is hard. It takes a lot of effort to make things work correctly - why are you making your own networking? Did you consider using existing solutions instead? There's plenty of ready solutions for all sorts of applications, you shouldn't deal with raw TCP unless you understand all of the associated concepts very well indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very simple solution to that when you're using the asynchronous callbacks (though I'd strongly recommend switching to a newer approach, or even better, an existing library - raw TCP is hard to do right).

The callback delegate can point to an instance method. This means you can have something like this:

```
class Client
{
  private readonly Socket socket;
  public readonly byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[BUFFFER_SIZE];

  public Client(Socket socket)
  {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
  {
    // Handle the received data as usual
  }
}
```

And then in your `AcceptCallback` method, just use a list of `Client` instead of `Socket`, and the final `BeginReceive` call as such:

```
var client = new Client(socket);
socket.BeginReceive(client.ReceiveBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, client.ReceiveCallback, 
                    socket);
clients.Add(newClient);
```

But again, writing custom networking is hard. Use an existing solution if possible - there's plenty to choose from.

Also, the `ObjectDisposedException`s you're getting are because you're doing `Shutdown` immediately followed by a `Close`. This is wrong. TCP shutdown is coöperative - you need to wait for the client socket to close before you call `Close` on your socket. What you're doing is rudely interrupting the connection before it has a chance to resolve itself. Again - TCP is hard to do right, you *need* to learn how it works very thoroughly.